# request to core data after changes in it gives the old value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i have this code into core data model for update a value into it:

```
if (!([photo.photoDescription isEqualToString:[photoDictionary[PHOTO_DESCRIPTION] description]])) {
        photo.photoDescription = [photoDictionary[PHOTO_DESCRIPTION] description];
        photo.isOnMap = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        [context save:&error];
    }
```

in my controller i have add an observer for looking the changes into core data:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificaRicevut) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.context];
```

when i execute the `[context save:&error];` code, the notify is correctly sent, but when i make a request inside the notification method for retrieve the new value, i get the old value instead the new one.
if i restart the app, the new value is show correctly. where is the problem? 
thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the new value ?  Also have you considered simply observing any changes to photo object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved by putting this code inside the notification method:

```
    - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:);
        [self.context performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        [self updateMapWithPictureInCoreData];
    });
}
```

Hope can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger) to inspect the database during run time. Problems like these are most often due to one of the following:

- Not calling `[managedObjectContext save:&error]` correctly
- Failing to create `NSManagedObject` or `NSManagedObjectContext` correctly